# Minimum requirements to power 2 USB-C monitiors on ARM architecture

Tags: memory, multiple-monitors, processor-architecture

I have 2 USB-C monitors where the computer powers and provide data transfer to both. I use a lot of progressive web apps as part of my day to day. MS Teams as one, is a major resource hog and without two monitors is ok, but with all the web apps open, Teams and the two monitors, I am noticing it all slow down.

Question is can ARM architecture run this kind of setup with more RAM or do I actually need a better processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAM is a big issue with multiple apps open, and ARM is very competative with x86 (see Apple M1), so if you see high RAM usage while using teams, try upgrading RAM.